# How should I use a queue with an unordered_set as the underlying container

Tags: c++, stl, std

I have a data structure containing a set of `std::pair<int, int>`. There are two important properties I require for this data structure:

- I can check set membership fast.
- FIFO

So as a C++ beginner armed with cppreference.com I went for `std::queue<std::unordered_set<PointUV, pointUVHash>> frontierPointsUV{};` where I have `typedef std::pair<int, int> PointUV;` and I include the implementation of `PointUVHash` in the appendix below.

My questions are

1. Is this a sensible way to meet the 2 requirements above?
2. How do I check set membership? I've tried `frontierPointsUV.c.contains` for set membership but I get "has no member" errors.
3. How to I push and pop (or insert and erase)? I've been unsuccessful with trying to call these modifiers on either of the containers.

**Appendix - Hash implementation**

```
struct pointUVHash final
{
  // This is a safe hashing function for pointUV because we only ever expect it to have 0 or positive ints
  // in ranges well under 2**16
  int operator()(const PointUV &p) const
  {
    return int(p.first) + (int(p.second) << 16);
  }
};
```

Comment: `std::queue` requires the container used for storage be a sequence container, which `std::unordered_set` is not a member of.

Comment: Seems contradictory: a queue has an order and an unordered set does not. You could probably add a bunch of code to make it work, but this kind of mismatch is usually better solved with a design change.

Comment: It really sounds like you want a [`bimap`](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.bimap) that would let you use an index for the key so you can maintain fifo order but still able to look up the value faster then a linear search.

Comment: @PeteBecker indeed it is contradictory. But if we forget my attempted solution. Is it a poor design to want a container that has fast membership check and also FIFO?

Comment: @NathanOliver I see what you mean, although I maybe should have said I want constant time lookup. Starting to sound like I need to code it up myself.

Comment: You are correct that `std::queue` has no `contains()` member.  `std::queue` limits access to the one element at the front of the queue.  If you need to search a container, that rules out directly using `std::queue`.

Comment: Can you afford to waste some space and have two containers? One for order and one for high-speed look-up? You'll want to wrap them in order to keep them in synch.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare Most likely you'll need to.  AFAIK there is no fifo container that provides constant time lookup.

Comment: @DrewDormann yeah so what I'm looking for is essentially a queue that wraps an unordered map, and calling its push/pop calls the underlying insert/erase, and calling contains calls the underlying contains

Comment: @user4581301 yes at this point that seems like a good idea

Comment: @Drew Dormann: be aware of iterator invalidation...

Comment: @StephanLechner I believe erasing an element from an `unordered_map` [preserves all other valid iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase).  Am I overlooking something?  If I'm giving poor advice, I'd love to know.

Comment: @Drew Dormann: insert, emplace, emplace_hint, operator[] may causes rehash, and rehash invalidates iterators (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map , iterator invalidation)

Comment: Thank you both.  <sips more coffee>  Deleting bad-idea comment that's too old to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue adaptor requires an ordered container such as deque or list to work. In my opinion, it is also obsolete as it only removes functionality from the underlying container and doesn't add anything of substance.

What you want is two data structures that are kept in-sync, e.g. one `unordered_set<pair<int, int> >` and one `deque<pair<int, int> >`. Seeing how `pair<int, int>` is a very simple type, this combination works best. If you start handling more complex types where you may want to avoid duplicate objects and lookups, storing pointers in one of the containers may be an option.

Anyway, something like this should do the trick:

```
class unique_queue
{
public:
    using value_type = std::pair<int, int>;
private:
    struct hash: private std::hash<int>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const value_type& value) const noexcept
        {
          if(sizeof(int) >= sizeof(std::size_t)) {
              const std::hash<int>& inthash = *this;
              return inthash(value.first) * 31 + inthash(value.second);
          }
          return static_cast<std::size_t>(value.first)
                << ((sizeof(std::size_t) - sizeof(int)) * CHAR_BIT)
                + static_cast<std::size_t>(value.second);
        }
    };
    using set_type = std::unordered_set<value_type, hash>;
    using queue_type = std::deque<value_type>;

    set_type set;
    queue_type queue;
public:
    bool push(const value_type& value)
    {
        std::pair<set_type::iterator, bool> inserted = set.insert(value);
        if(! inserted.second) // equal value already contained
            return false;
        try {
            queue.push_back(value);
        } catch(...) { // provide exception safety
            set.erase(inserted.first);
            throw;
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool empty() const noexcept
    { return queue.empty(); }

    const value_type& front() const noexcept
    { return queue.front(); }

    void pop() noexcept
    {
        set.erase(front());
        queue.pop_front();
    }
    bool contained(const value_type& value) const noexcept
    { return set.count(value) != 0; }
};
```

I've kept the function semantics somewhat close to what queue or deque provide, e.g. undefined behavior if `front()` is called on an empty queue.

If you want multiple equal keys in your queue, the easiest way is to replace `unordered_set<pair<int, int> >` with `unordered_map<pair<int, int>, size_t>` to keep track of how many equal keys are in the queue. Something like this:

```
class set_queue
{
public:
    using value_type = std::pair<int, int>;
private:
    struct hash: private std::hash<int>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const value_type& value) const noexcept
        {
          if(sizeof(int) >= sizeof(std::size_t)) {
              const std::hash<int>& inthash = *this;
              return inthash(value.first) * 31 + inthash(value.second);
          }
          return static_cast<std::size_t>(value.first)
                << ((sizeof(std::size_t) - sizeof(int)) * CHAR_BIT)
                + static_cast<std::size_t>(value.second);
        }
    };
    using map_type = std::unordered_map<value_type, std::size_t, hash>;
    using queue_type = std::deque<value_type>;

    map_type map;
    queue_type queue;
public:
    bool push(const value_type& value)
    {
        std::pair<map_type::iterator, bool> inserted = map.emplace(value, 0);
        try {
            queue.push_back(value);
        } catch(...) { // provide exception safety
            if(inserted.second)
                map.erase(inserted.first);
            throw;
        }
        inserted.first->second += 1;
        return true;
    }
    bool empty() const noexcept
    { return queue.empty(); }

    const value_type& front() const noexcept
    { return queue.front(); }

    void pop() noexcept
    {
        map_type::iterator refcount = map.find(front());
        assert(refcount != map.end());
        queue.pop_front();
        refcount->second -= 1;
        if(! refcount->second) // last element of same value
            map.erase(refcount);
    }
    std::size_t count(const value_type& value) const noexcept
    {
        map_type::const_iterator found = map.find(value);
        return found == map.end() ? 0 : found->second;
    }
};
```

Comment: A note on the obsolescence of queue: The access restriction are  what make the queue useful... when you need a queue. If the restrictions are not useful, you probably didn't need a queue.

Comment: @user4581301 and then you write your program with queue until you add one place where queue.clear() would be useful. Then you rewrite everything with the slightly different method names for deque. *shrugs*. Whatever floats your boat

Comment: That says you didn't want a queue. You just didn't know it until too late.